# How to import from one level above the current package in groovy

Tags: groovy, import, project

My project structure is as follows:

```
groovy / action / TestDataHelper
groovy / SharedState
```

I'm trying to import my SharedState script from my TestDataHelper.

If I use

```
package action
```

in TestDataHelper, that class itself is happy, but can't see SharedState. If I don't use a package, the class itself is unhappy, but can see SharedState

I haven't been able to find an answer on google yet.
How do I handle this in groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind :-)

I found out that I can't import from the main package, in my case `groovy`.
To solve it, I put the SharedState into a package - and then imported that package from TestDataHelper.

I do find it weird though, that that should be necessary.

Comment: If groovy actually here _is_ a package (which i doubt, because it's more likely the root of a source set -- but without seeing the full project, this is guesswork), then you would just use `groovy.SharedState`.  Provide a proper root package instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I am not aware of the correct terms, hence 'main package'.
Shouldn't all sub-packages automatically inherit from this 'root of a source set' ?