# How to import from one level above the current package in groovy - elaboration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a very similar issue to what is described here:
[How to import from one level above the current package in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51497755/how-to-import-from-one-level-above-the-current-package-in-groovy)

I don't want to move SharedState to an action/pkg subdirectory. What I want to do is to maintain the following structure:

- groovy / action / TestDataHelper
- groovy / action2 / TestDataHelper2
- groovy / action3 / SharedState

and then gain access to SharedState from both TestDataHelper and TestDataHelper2.

I cannot do that anyhow using package, which I tend to understand is impossible by default. I could use classpath shenanigans instead, but need some guidance on that first.

Thanks for any kind of feedback.

Comment: Without knowing your build tool this is hard to give good advice here.  The general answer here is: adjust your classpath so the source roots match your packages.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using groovy scripts within Jenkins automated jobs. I need to generate a Jenkins job with a seed job basing on a groovy script.

Comment: I have adjusted the tags, to what makes sense from a groovy-but-not-jenkins-user - feel free to adjust.

Comment: OK, thanks. Sorry, did not mean to cause any missunderstandings. I've learnt that if I export CLASSPATH variable to given path in ~/.bashrc file, I am able to println it in the groovy script and it matches the value. I a  now working on being further able to import methods from different directories taking advantage of the CLASSPATH being set, but I'm failing.

Comment: my comment is for groovy, not jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use additional class path in the Jenkins job seed job - advanced section in the Build. The path needs to be matching mother directory of the project.

/home/user/mother_dir

The groovy script can be anywhere under /home/user/mother_dir, in my case it's under /home/user/mother_dir/other_dir/script.groovy

Then, I put the classes I would like to import within a package in a /home/user/mother_dir/package_dir. In the groovy script mapped with the job I import package.* and have access to all the necessary classes from the package_dir.